# Filter One Dataframe by Shared Values in Another: filter() and %in% commands not working

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

Would love help with this issue. I have a dataframe:

```
> df1
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   title                            type                
   <chr>                            <chr>               
 1 "Youtube for information about " Research Paper      
 2 "YOUNG STROKE DUE TO MULTIPLE R" Case Report         
 3 "Xanthine Oxidase Inhibitors fo" Review Article      
 4 "Wrist pain: prevalence and ris" Review Article      
 5 "Worldwide expert agreement on " Research Paper      
 6 "Work Productivity and Economic" Research Paper      
 7 "Widespread Pain Prior to Total" Research Paper      
 8 "Why we should definitely inclu" Review Article      
 9 "Whole spine and sacroiliac joi" Research Paper      
10 "Whole exome sequencing in earl" Research Paper      
11 "Whole-Organ Magnetic Resonance" Research Paper      
12 "WHICH RISK FACTORS DETERMINE C" Research Paper      
13 "Which precautions should be ta" Letter to the Editor
14 "Which patients with Systemic L" Research Paper      
15 "WHICH IS THE MOST SENSITIVE AC" Research Paper      
16 "What we already know about the" Review Article      
17 "What is the site of pain osteo" Letter to the Editor
18 "What is the role of HIF-1a, HI" Review Article      
19 "What Is the Prevalence of Cogn" Review Article      
20 "What have we learned from traj" Review Article
```

I want to ONLY retain the values that have a title that is NOT in another dataframe. Ie, the following would be EXCLUDED from the first dataframe:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  title                            type          
  <chr>                            <chr>         
1 "Youtube for information about " Research Paper
2 "YOUNG STROKE DUE TO MULTIPLE R" Case Report   
3 "Work Productivity and Economic" Research Paper
4 "WHICH IS THE MOST SENSITIVE AC" Research Paper
5 "What is the role of HIF-1Î±, H" Review Article
```

I tried to just negate the %in% operator, but that returns df1 in its entirety:

```
> df1 %>% filter(!(title %in% df2$title))

### gives df1, not reproducing here for brevity
```

But even weirder, if I remove the negate (and should just be searching) I get an empty table. What am I doing wrong?

```
> df1 %>% filter(title %in% df2$title)
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: title <chr>, type <chr>
>
```

I know I could use antijoin or something along those lines, but the actual dataset has many more columsn and thousands of rows so I need to figure out how to do this in code properly using the %in% function. Thanks!!!!

Comment: `df1 <- df1 %>% filter(!(title %in% df2$title))` should work. Can you provide data in a reproducible form (using `dput`) for us to check ?

Answer (score 1):

We could use `anti_join` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1,df2, by="title")
```

```
                            title                 type
6  Work Productivity and Economic       Research Paper
7  Widespread Pain Prior to Total       Research Paper
8  Why we should definitely inclu       Review Article
9  Whole spine and sacroiliac joi       Research Paper
10 Whole exome sequencing in earl       Research Paper
11 Whole-Organ Magnetic Resonance       Research Paper
12 WHICH RISK FACTORS DETERMINE C       Research Paper
13 Which precautions should be ta Letter to the Editor
14 Which patients with Systemic L       Research Paper
15 WHICH IS THE MOST SENSITIVE AC       Research Paper
16 What we already know about the       Review Article
17 What is the site of pain osteo Letter to the Editor
18 What is the role of HIF-1a, HI       Review Article
19 What Is the Prevalence of Cogn       Review Article
20 What have we learned from traj       Review Article
```